# How to correctly add a font Mime map in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, font-awesome

Other posts in SO suggested me adding

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
```

or

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/woff" />
```

for the `font-awesome` icons.

But after I have

```
<system.webServer>    
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/woff" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

I found all my other static resources cannot be loaded. My browser console points out all the `GET` for `.js`, `.css`, `.png`, etc ended with a 500 Internal Server Error.

So how can I just add one mime type without remove all other existing mime maps?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2009/12/04/iis7-error-cannot-add-duplicate-collection-entry-of-type-mimemap-with-unique-key-attribute-fileextension.aspx).

Since we cannot have duplicate mimemap, I need to add a remove.

```
<system.webServer>    
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/woff" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

And I find both `application/woff` and `application/x-woff` will work.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I found the problem. It is the duplicate mimeMap that caused the issue.